# Starting character with cube or six sided cylinder?

Tags: modeling, objects

I always start with a Cube, but recently I saw some tutorials which are starting character with a six sided cylinder. The result at the end is same, after I add my loop cuts, but I am still interested if its there any advantage of this method or is it just preference of an artist?

I would just like to mention that I prefer cube because it makes me feel like I am more in control where edges and cuts gonna be. The question would be: **Does it make any difference, at the end, starting with six sided?**

Comment: The general idea (usually) is to start with as little geometry as you can get away with depending on the shape of the object you want to make (especially if you plan to subdivide later). Therefore, if a cube works just fine for what you need to do, it has 2 less faces than the cylinder, and therefore is probably preferable.

Comment: A cube is not a good idea.The more angular the basic shape is, the worse it looks when it's rigged. Use a prism and make it rounder with e.g. Smooth modifier.